# MKMapView rotates when dragging instead of keep heading

Tags: ios, mkmapview

i am setting `MKMapView` object in my app to show the user location and to keep the map locked on the device heading like so :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];
   [self firstSetMapView];
}

-(void)firstSetMapView{
    _map_view.delegate = self;
    _map_view.showsUserLocation = YES;
    _map_view.userTrackingMode = MKUserTrackingModeFollowWithHeading;
 }
```

it works great if i am not dragging the map. if i change the zoom level it works fine as expected.
the thing is when i drag the map i see the map rotated to another heading, `MKUserTrackingModeFollow` so i have implemented this code :

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didChangeUserTrackingMode:(MKUserTrackingMode)mode animated:(BOOL)animated {
   if (mapView.userTrackingMode != MKUserTrackingModeFollowWithHeading) {
        [mapView setUserTrackingMode:MKUserTrackingModeFollowWithHeading];
    }
}
```

so now the heading is returning but only after the wired rotation happens.

how can i manage this?
thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to have your own code to keep the rotation where you want to. Half of `MKUserTrackingModeFollowWithHeading` is the `Follow` part and by dragging the map somewhere else you've stopping the following. When the Location Manager updates the user's location you can read the heading off that and rotate the MKMapview to that value.